# Multiple xmlhttp requests - JSON get's overwritten

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I have to do mutiple xmlhttp requests (one for each country). The problem is that my JSON always get's overwritten to the result of last request. is there anyway I can fix this? here's the code.

```
function getDataBetween()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < CountryNames.length; i++) 
    {
        var countryName = CountryNames[i];
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
            {
                for (var a = 0; a < CountryNames.length; a++) 
                {
                    dataset[a] = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    console.log(dataset[a]);
                }
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","update.php?country=" + countryName + "&begin=" + beginTime + "&end=" + endTime + "&functionName=getActiveUsers", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    DrawStructure();
}
```

I've looked for the Promise syntax, but I'm not sure how to use it in this case, and I've tried mutiple things but I can't get it to work.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I highly recommend using a library for handling ajax requests like http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ or https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent

Comment: I understand, but in this case it's not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of separate `xmlHttpRequest` objects for each request.  As it is now, your `for` loop is using the same variable to store them all, thus they following ones overwrite the later ones.  There are various ways to solve this.  One way is to add a closure so that each invocation of the `for` loop has it's own function scope:

```
function getDataBetween()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < CountryNames.length; i++) 
    {
        (function() {
            var countryName = CountryNames[i];
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
                {
                    for (var a = 0; a < CountryNames.length; a++) 
                    {
                        dataset[a] = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        console.log(dataset[a]);
                    }
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","update.php?country=" + countryName + "&begin=" + beginTime + "&end=" + endTime + "&functionName=getActiveUsers", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        })();
    }
    DrawStructure();
}
```

You could also change your references to `xmlhttp` to be references to `this` so you aren't using your `xmlhttp` variable directly in the `onreadystatechange` handler after it's been overwritten:

```
function getDataBetween()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < CountryNames.length; i++) 
    {
        var countryName = CountryNames[i];
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) 
            {
                for (var a = 0; a < CountryNames.length; a++) 
                {
                    dataset[a] = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    console.log(dataset[a]);
                }
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","update.php?country=" + countryName + "&begin=" + beginTime + "&end=" + endTime + "&functionName=getActiveUsers", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    DrawStructure();
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. Thanks for explaing your answer aswell, now I understand, I won't the same mistake in the future!